# Why does my Roblox game crash with more than 2 players or after a short delay?

Tags: lua, roblox

My game, is aimed to have around 20-30 players in one server, keeps crashing with 1-2 players after a short delay. If 3 or more try to join, it crashes instantly. Sometimes it doesn't even allow 1 person to join. It often gives the ID=17, with Errors 277 or 279, or to check their internet connection.

The map isn't especially large, it consists of 3 small islands made out of terrain, with bridges and water in-between. There are a couple of buildings and a couple of scripts running. [A duplicate of the game can be found here](https://web.roblox.com/games/6451079132/8910buts-Place-Number-199), which is exactly the same, just stored under a different game (to protect the original).

I've tried disabling the API services and HTTP services individually and 3rd party stuff is always off as I never use it. Some audio files, taken from the Roblox verified music and Monstercat, occasionally don't play properly in the radio, but I'm not sure if this is related. I've also tried running it in "Testservice" but it still doesn't want to work, same errors. It runs perfectly in Normal Roblox studio running.

Any help is appreciated, please ask if you need anything else.

As it's such a diverse range of things it could possibly be, I'm unsure which code parts would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an error in your internet connection or computer. The game worked well for me. There are lots of possible fixes to this problem. Here are some of them:

1. Disable your firewall/antivirus
2. Unplug your router for a minute, turn off devices connected to it, and then restart.
3. Reinstall the game
4. Try playing the game in another wifi connection
5. Open Ports. You may not be able to play Roblox as a result of you not forwarding
   ports. Here are the relevant ports you’ll need to open, along with instructions on how
   to open them:
   ROBLOX PC PORTS:

   UDP: 49152–65535

   Here’s how to open these ports:

   Log in as admin to your router.
   Navigate to the port forwarding category.
   Enter the IP address of your PC or console.
   Enter the TCP and/or the UDP ports for Roblox.
   Restart your router.

Links from the sites I got that information:
https://whatt.org/errors/roblox-error-code-277-fix/
https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/560789-how-to-fix-roblox-error-code-279-id-17

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. Recently, it has been working for me with one account, perfectly fine. When a friend joins, it sometimes crashes. When a third player connects, it instantly seems to crash. Multiple people have reported the error so it's not likely a client issue.

Comment: That's true, when my friend joined, it crashed. I guess it's a bad script.

Comment: When did the game start crashing? Did you use free models?

Comment: I tried my one hundred percent best to program scripts my self. It started crashing the first time that more than one person joined. There are only free models with scripts removed (props or car bodies).

Comment: If the game started crashing the first time, it could be a studio/roblox bug.

Comment: You can create a copy of your game and see if it's going to crash. If it crashes, remove the scripts one by one, and if it doesn't work, delete the props one by one.

Comment: And then, if it doesn't work, you'll need to remake the game completely, because the files may be corrupted.

Comment: The linked game is an exact duplicate of the original, and you say that crashes so that's ruled out. I can try removing the scripts one by one but do you know how to use test service, I don't but I feel as if it would be useful. Thanks for the help, this is the second time I've made this game.

Comment: You are welcome. According to the API reference,  "The TestService is a service used by Roblox internally to run analytical tests on their engine. It makes it possible to write sophisticated tests right inside a game". I guess it's only used for really advanced purposes, Not for casual tests. Here's the API reference link: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TestService

Comment: Does it start crashing after you add scripts and models, or does it start crashing when you create the game(with the baseplate only)? Did you enable any beta feature?

Comment: Did you try to run a server in Studio with more than one player?

Comment: Hello, I've tried running the game locally in Roblox Studio with around 5 Players and it gave the same message as in Roblox. I don't know whether it was crashing before or after things were added as I only tested it in Roblox afterwards.

Comment: No scripts broke, interesting. You should try creating a new game and not add anything(just let the baseplate) and test it to see if crashes. If it does, it's a problem in Roblox Studio, not in scripts or etc...

Comment: Hello, I've been working hard at testing all the scripts. So far I've tried disabling almost every single script & a similar world with no scripts in (which worked with 3 people).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your continuous help @Arthur Buzas Baccan , I have some-how fixed it, I'm not entirely sure how, Once the game is done, I will update this post with a link to it for reference. Many thanks, Mr Frog.

Comment: You are welcome, it was a pleasure to help you.